# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: unable to load from [netlib-native_system-win-x86_64.dll]

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run the java projection written by other people using eclipse in my computer, and my os is win-7 64bits, but the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: unable to load from [netlib-native_system-win-x86_64.dll]" always happens. What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks so much!I really need help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cJrW.png)

Comment: please, show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Scala Breeze Unable to load windows 64 dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826607/scala-breeze-unable-to-load-windows-64-dll)

It seems to be the same.

Hope helps

Comment: Thank you very much! However I cannot understand how to  set the JVM properties as that answer. So could you help me?